# Why apk isn't compatible from Google Play for Gigabyte GSmart G1345

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

The **AndroidManifest** except for **Activities** is:

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto"
      android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1"
package="..."
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:theme="@style/app_theme">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
                  android:required="true"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".general.StartActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

[image]

Comment: What means the russian stuff on your screenshot?

Comment: It means that apk isn't compatible in the Compatible Devices List from Google Play for Gigabyte GSmart G1345 (msm7627_sku2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the developer console, turn off the option Copy Protection. For me it's working, Acer Iconita Tab a500, stupidly did not app on market, and the link from browser says "is not compatible". Google Support advised to disable copy protection (this option doesn't shows app for rooted devices).

Comment: I'll not turned off Copy Protection. I'll use Application Licensing in nearest future. Hope this'll help.

Comment: I've changed the code for using **LVL** and than turned off the option **Copy Protection**. App isn't compatible in the Compatible Devices List from Google Play for Gigabyte GSmart G1345 (msm7627_sku2). But the owner of that device tald me that now this app is compatible for his GSmart G1345. So, he installed it from Google Play. Thanks!!!